# Toggling check boxes in MultiChoice AlertDialog in android

Tags: android

> Hi,
>
> I have created the **MultiChoice
>   AlertDialog** The AlertDialog has five
>   list items with checkboxes. When I
>   check First checkbox, w.r.t this the
>   if the other checkboxes in the list
>   are checked they shud be unchecked
>   automatically and vice versa.
>
> I am checking the **isChecked** status
>   in the **onClick** method of
>   **OnMultiChoiceClickListener()** and calling the
>   **showDialog(DIALOG_MULTIPLE_CHOICE);** by updating **boolean[]
>   checkedItems;**  to recreate the
>   Dialog, But I am unable to achieve it.
>   If you any suggestions please direct
>   me to right way.

**Is there any way to recreate the AleartDialog onClick event of the radio button click.**

Some Sample Code below:

```
case DIALOG_MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
final String[] lJobTypes = { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3","Item4", "Item5" };
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(JoblistPage.this)
    // .setIcon(R.drawable.logo)
    .setTitle("Title Here")
    // .setCustomTitle(m_Title)
    .setMultiChoiceItems(lTypes, m_Selections,
        new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton, boolean isChecked) {
                /* User clicked on a check box do some stuff */
                if (isChecked) {
                    m_CheckCount++;
                    //Toggle the Radio button Check status
                } else {
                    m_CheckCount--;
                }
                                                }
        }).setPositiveButton("Ok",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int whichButton) {
                    }
                }).create();
```

Regards
Vinayak

Comment: Did you mean to use a RadioButton? What are all of the Attributes? Why don't you post some of the code to remove some of the guesswork?

Comment: HI JackN, I have updated the Question with code, that may make u more clear

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't recreate the dialog, just toggle the checkboxes within the current dialog.  Your onMultiChoiceClickListener can keep track of the currently active checkbox (if any) and uncheck it when another is selected.  Here's a complete tested, working example:

```
package com.stackoverflow.beekeeper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StackOverflowTest extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }

  private int mSelected = -1;

  @Override protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final Builder build = new Builder(this);
    build.setTitle("List selection");
    build.setCancelable(true);
    final String[] strings = new String[]{"Cow", "Horse", "Goat"};
    final OnMultiChoiceClickListener onClick =
      new OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                                      final int which, final boolean isChecked) {

          if (isChecked) {
            if ((mSelected != -1) && (mSelected != which)) {
              final int oldVal = mSelected;
              final AlertDialog alert = (AlertDialog)dialog;
              final ListView list = alert.getListView();
              list.setItemChecked(oldVal, false);
            }
            mSelected = which;
          } else
            mSelected = -1;
        }
      };
    build.setMultiChoiceItems(strings, null, onClick);
    build.setPositiveButton("Done", new OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                                    final int which) {
        String message = null;
        if (mSelected == -1)
          message = "You didn't select anything.";
        else
          message = "You selected '" + strings[mSelected] + "'";
        Toast.makeText(StackOverflowTest.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    });
    build.show();
  }
}
```

One thing to watch for: you must specify "null" for the "checkedItems" parameter in your "setMultiChoiceItems" call -- otherwise the "setItemChecked" calls won't work as expected.  It would end up using that array to store the checked state, and "setItemChecked" would'nt update it correctly, so everything would get confused.  Odd, but true.

Comment: hooray, thanks so much; it works. For some reason it's hard to google for the solution to this problem

Answer (score 7):

I was struggling with this for quite some time.  I maintain an array of the "checked" status of each of the items and change that value while visually changing the setItemChecked value.  Then when the done button is clicked I iterate through "checked" to save the values to my db.

```
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(cats, checked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item, boolean check) {
            if(cats[item].equals("All Categories")) {
                AlertDialog d = (AlertDialog) dialog;
                ListView v = d.getListView();
                int i = 0;
                while(i < cats.length) {
                    v.setItemChecked(i, check);
                    checked[i] = check;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            checked[item] = check;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try replacing `setMultiChoiceItems` to `setSingleChoiceItems` in your dialog?

Comment: Then there would be no matter of toggling the check boxes... I want multiple choice in that this toggling feature (list1 checkbos is checked then List2,list3.list4,list5 should be unchecked and if any of the 2,3,4 or 5 is checked the list1 checkbox shub be unchecked)

Comment: Also take into account as what button position is clicked. Check for the parameter called "whichbutton" it should give you the position of the item that has been clicked

Comment: Yea but how to recreate the dialog at that event