# Show multiple selections in AlertBuilder created as SingleChoiceItem list

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I'm using a alert dialog created with the alertBuilder & setSingleChoiceItems to assign a single choice value to a selected entry in a list of data entries.  This works well for a single selection, where the old value is used to set the selection when creating the dialog and the new value is picked up when the user clicks, i.e:

```
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, currentLevel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int newLevel) {
            if (newLevel == currentLevel) {
                // no change
            } else {
                updateLevel(alertId,newLevel);
            }
            dialog.cancel();
        }
});
```

Now I'd like to extend this to multiple selections of data elements, which means that there could be several different current levels, so when building the dialog I should be able to select multiple entries, but only a single choice is possible on click (which will replace all the initial multiple selections).   I still would like to have the radio buttons  (unlike the check boxes that I would get by using the setMultipleChoiceItems).

Any tips how to implement this ?  Do I need to create my custom view  or is there a way to set the AlertBuilder to support this ?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608018/toggling-check-boxes-in-multichoice-alertdialog-in-android

Comment: I think that solution still will show check boxes not radio buttons..