# Checked checkbox should not be unchecked

Tags: android, checkbox, checkboxlist, android-checkbox

I have Alert Dialog with multiplechoiceItems. In which some are already checked values according to parsing. I want that values which are already checked, should not be unchecked.Please help me if any 1 have any idea.

Comment: Add this in your <checkbox  android:clickable="false"/>

Comment: post your code.if you didnt get output still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make them disable which are already checked

Comment: Actually checked values are coming form server and even i don't know the values which are checked. so How can I make them disable? I am getting values dynamically.

Comment: Suppose you are having 10 ckeckboxes and out of them seven are checked, then you have to do 1 thing, when you are setting them checked according server values at that point of time make them disable also.

Comment: Please check this if you have multichoiceitems : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183610/android-how-to-disable-list-items-on-list-creation

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't too clear, but something like this might work:

```
yourCheckboxID.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {  
        if (isChecked){
        yourCheckboxID.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});
```

or you may need:

```
if(yourCheckboxID.isChecked()){
   yourCheckboxID.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Let me know if that's what you were after!

Comment: Actually its not checkbox but its AlertDialog with multichoiceItems. Sorry I mentioned wrong in Question, now I edited it.

Comment: OK well, use an OnMultiChoiceClickListener(), see [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608018/toggling-check-boxes-in-multichoice-alertdialog-in-android[/link]

Answer (score 0):

When a Checkbox is checked/unchecked you can handle in an event called `OnCheckedChangedListener`

For example:

```
CheckBox cb;
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    //In case that the new isChecked is false, you let it true again
    if(!isChecked)
        buttonView.setChecked(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually its not checkbox but its AlertDialog with multichoiceItems. Sorry I mentioned wrong in Question, now I edited it.