# AlertDialog with both single choice and multi choice items

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an alert dialog and would like to have three options that a user can choose one of, and an additional option that a user can toggle on or off.

Is this possible? When I try and add both single and multi choice items the second overwrites the first.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ContactListActivity.this);
builder.setTitle(R.string.sort_dialog_title);

builder.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.sort_options_array, -1, null);
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.sort_reverse_option, null, null);
```

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608018/toggling-check-boxes-in-multichoice-alertdialog-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You can keep Anything that you require in your AlertDialog. Method is simple. I am giving an example so that you can get the idea and make your one.

- Write a layout of what you require in your AlertDialog. Simply you'll write it in xml.

  ```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/root"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/email"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
          android:hint="Buyer&apos;s email address..."
          android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```
- Say, the above file is named alert.xml . Then Inflate the alert.xml and set it as the view of your alert dialog

  ```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this); 
  builder.setTitle("Title"); 
  builder.setMessage("message"); 
  LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert, null); 
  final EditText email = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.email); 
  builder.setView(view);
  ```
- Now set your positive and negative button and set the actions.

  ```
  builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1){
               // Do what you need to do
              }
          });

  builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1){
                  dialog.dismiss();
              }
          });
  ```
- Show the alert

  ```
  AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
  dialog.show();
  ```

You have to just change the layout and write your required one , Rest are same. Hope it helps.