# Checklist don't stay checked

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a problem with my checklist. When an user check one of the items and validates, the checked items aren't stored. Every time you open a new dialog, the checklist s reset.

How can I store them?

Here is my code :

```
else if(position == 1){
final ArrayList<Integer> mSelectedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle("Titre")
       .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.liste_choix, null,
               new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                       boolean isChecked) {
                   if (isChecked) {
                       mSelectedItems.add(which);
                   } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {
                       mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                   }
               }
       })
       .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User clicked OK, so save the mSelectedItems results somewhere
                   // or return them to the component that opened the dialog
               }
           })
       .setNegativeButton(R.string.annuler, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               }
           });

builder.show();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to mSelectedItems. Because everything above is happening after a conditional it looks as though this is all taking place with in a method. As you create a new mSelectedItems instance each time you get to this part of the conditional, the list will be empty every time you start. What I suggest you do is:

(1) actually make mSelectedItems a member or instance variable if that's your intention, this way its not recreate every time you get to that part of the code

(2) then all you have to do is check which ones were previously selected last time toggling the boxes like they do in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608018/toggling-check-boxes-in-multichoice-alertdialog-in-android).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right about (1) but (2) isn't what I'm looking for. When someone exists my app, I want the checked box to remain checked. So, when he comes back again, they are still checked.

Comment: So you need to store the selections somewhere - have you looked into using `SharedPreferences`, `SQLite`, an external webserver or some other persistent method of storage? `SharedPreferences` is probably the easiest to use. If you just store the data there and then reload next time the person comes back you can store that way. You could also probably use `SavedInstanceState` to do the same thing.