# How to set checkbox checked and disabled

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-checkbox

I have this code for showing list of languages for download:

```
public void onCreateDialog(ArrayList<String>fullLangArray, final ArrayList<String>codeLangArray) {

    final String[] items = fullLangArray.toArray(new String[fullLangArray.size()]);

    final ArrayList mSelectedItems = new ArrayList();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    // Set the dialog title
    builder.setTitle("Updates...")
            .setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected,
                                            boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                  mSelectedItems.add(Utils.SERVER_ADDRESS + "/" + codeLangArray.get(indexSelected) + ".zip");
                            } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(indexSelected)) {
                                  mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
                            }
                        }
                    })

            .setPositiveButton("Download", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(MainActivity.this);
                    downloadTask.execute(mSelectedItems.toString());

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

I want to make a one item of a checkbox is checked and "**disabled**" like in a photo (*Option 3*) when AlertDialog is loaded.

[image]

Can you help me how to do it?

Comment: simply calling checkBox.setChecked(true/false) and checkbox.setEnabled(true/false).....or did I misunderstood the question?

Comment: you can use your_checkbox.setChecked(true);your_checkbox.setEnabled(false);

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, Edited description.

Comment: so you just want the box a little bit transparent but not the text?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, it doesn't matter transparent or not, user could not uncheck the item. The item always should be checked.

Comment: then Jois way is what you need....set Your checkbox checked by checkBox.setChecked(true) and disable it with checkBox.setEnabled(false)....that´s all

Comment: I think this could give you a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608018/toggling-check-boxes-in-multichoice-alertdialog-in-android

Answer (score 9):

You can check the checkbox by using the `setChecked()` method which boolean value as parameter.

Example:

```
   option1.setChecked(true);
```

and also uncheck it using

```
   option2.setChecked(false);
```

If you want to set it to checked and disabled you have use setEnabled() which takes boolean as it's parameters.

Example.

```
option3.setChecked(true);
option3.setEnabled(false);
```

This will disable your checkbox and even check it. I hope this was helpful. ThankYou.

Comment: in multichoiceItems onclick(). If this helped you please dont forget to tick and vote . ThankYou

Answer (score 0):

**For setting Opacity**

> mSelectedItems.getBackground().setAlpha(128);

Where the INT ranges from 0 (fully transparent) to 255 (fully opaque).

**For setChecked item**

> mSelectedItems.setChecked(true);

**Disable checking**

> mSelectedItems.setEnabled(false)